# c++11 std::notify_all and spurious wakeup

Tags: c++, c++11, locking, condition-variable, spurious-wakeup

with c++11.
As `std::notify_all` would cause spurious wakeup, then why `std::notify_all` is remained but not `std::notify_one` all the time?
And could `std::notify_one`  cause spurious wakeup by the way?

---

elaborating my doubts:

When I call `std::condition_variable.wait/wait_for/wait_until` and `std::notify_XXX`, my purpose is generally to implement thread sychronisation. That is to say, more threads blocked to wait until another thread to notify only one of them to unblock.

Then I can just call `notify_one` to achieve that, but why there's another `notify_all`,  what is its purpose, or what situation is `notify_all` suitable for?
And in my situation, when I call `notify_all`, it will wakeup all waiting threads, then only one thread actually unblock and others remains blocking, is it called spurious wakeup?
And if `notify_one` would call spurious wakeup as well?

Comment: "_As std::notify_all would cause spurious wakeup_": The purpose of `notify_all` is to wake up all threads. That wouldn't be spurious, but intended. So I am not sure what your concern here is. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @user17732522 enn I add an additional discription of my doubts under my original question, I hope that could elaborate my doubts and hopefully for an answer~~

Comment: @user17732522 -- a spurious wakeup is one that's not triggered by a notify (or by timeout in the case of timed waits). The concern is valid: all of the `wait` functions can wake up spuriously.

Comment: user17732522 and PeteBecker are both right, but I guess the OP doesn't know what the 'spurious wakeup' is, and because of that many sentences in this question don't make sense. Eg. OP said _"`std::notify_all` would cause spurious wakeup"_ but that's not 'spurious wakeup' if the thread is unblocked by `std::notify_xxx`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On `void std::condition_variable::wait(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& lock);` from
[`thread.condition`/8.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/thread.condition#condvar-8.3):

> The function will unblock when signaled by a call to `notify_­one()` or a call to `notify_­all()`, **or spuriously**.

So calling `notify_­one()` or `notify_­all()` is not a prerequisite. It can unblock without any of those being called.

---

The above quote is from *"C++20 first post-publication draft"* but has remained the same since it was first written for C++11.

---

> why there's another `notify_all`, what is its purpose, or what situation is `notify_all` suitable for?

When you want all waiting threads to unblock. A practical situation would be when it's time to shutdown. If you have threads blocked in a `wait` they will never finish and `join()`ing them will hang.

Example with a predicate saying that it should wait until either `aborted` is `true` or `queue.empty()` is `false`:

```cpp
bool pop_from_queue(T& item) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    while(queue.empty() && not aborted) cv.wait(lock);
    if(aborted) return false;        // time to shutdown
    // else pick an item from the queue
    item = std::move(queue.front());
    queue.pop();
    return true;
}
```

When it's time to shutdown, another thread would here typically do:

```
aborted = true;   // std::atomic<bool>
cv.notify_all();
```

> when I call nitify_all, it will wakeup all waiting threads, then only one thread actually unblock and others remains blocking, is it called spurious wakeup?

No. A spurious wakeup is a wakeup that can happen at any time. If you call `notify_all`, the waiting threads will all wakeup as ordered - not spuriously.

> And if notify_one would call spurious wakeup as well?

It may cause a spurious wakeup, but that would be an implementation detail. The best thing is to just live with the fact that the threads may wakeup at any time and just check the predicate when they do.

> could I precislly control where to unblock in the waiting thread(who called `condition_variable.wait` with no Predicate)?

Without checking the predicate, the only thing the thread knows for sure is that it woke up. It does not now if it's for the right reason or not.

Comment: but if so, could I precislly control where to unblock in the waiting thread(who called condition_variable.wait with no Predicate)?

Comment: @f1msch I've tried to answer that by updating the qestion. Please let me know if I"ve missed anything.

Comment: _"It may cause a spurious wakeup, but that would be an implementation detail."_ - How can it be a 'spurious wakeup' if `notify_one` is the one who unblocks the thread?

Comment: @starriet주녕차 The standard says about `wait()`: _"The function will unblock when signaled by a call to `notify_one()` or a call to `notify_all()`, or spuriously."_ - so it may even wake up without any notification function having been called. A `notify_one()` could in some implementation trigger a deliberate wakeup of one thread + any number of other waiting threads. Those would then have been woken up spuriously.

Comment: Thanks, your quote from the standard is exactly what I'm thinking. So you mean, in some implementations, even though `notify_one()` "deliberately" wakes up only thread1, somehow that causes thread2,3 to wake up, for example? If that's the case, then I think the wakeup of thread2,3 is not 100% pure 'spurious' wakeup, since `notify_one()` is somehow involved in their wakeups. Please let me know if I didn't understand correctly. (The point I'm confused about is that I thought wakeup by `notify_xxx` is _not_ a spurious wakeup, but you said `notify_xxx` may cause a spurious wakeup.)

Comment: @starriet주녕차 I'm not saying that any implementation actually do that, but the standard doesn't specify approved causes for the spurious wakeups. An implementation is allowed to spuriously wake a waiting thread, so if it makes sense in the implementation, it could do it as a side effect of `notify_one` being called. `notify_one` is specified to wake one waiting thread so any extra threads being woken up only to find that the condition is not met would be spuriously woken up.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Later I should research further what are the causes of spurious wakeup, maybe it's related to OS and quite complicated though. P.S. It seems the OP didn't know the meaning of 'spurious wakeup' when he/she wrote the question.

Comment: @starriet주녕차 I think the reason is because the of posix's implementation of the fundamental building blocks. I read that allowing spurious wakeups also allows some implementation optimization in `pthreads`. It must be some pretty hefty optimization though because these spurious wakeups almost always confuses people.  To my knowledge, the Windows fundamentals for the same thing never triggers spuriously - at least not when used directly and you `WaitForSingleObject`/`WaitForMultipleObjects`. When those return, something real _will_ have happened.